# How to connect to MSSQL by using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sql-server, activex

I have some routine task (change some column types in MSSQL) on multiple server. 
So, I'm trying to make a script program that connects to MSSQL and change structure of some tables.

What I've done so far...
I made a text file on Desktop and wrote the code below in the file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var objConnection = new ActiveXObject("adodb.connection");
        var strConn = "driver={sql server};server=192.168.139.121;database=mytest;uid=testuser;password=testpw";
        objConnection.Open(strConn);
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

        (queries for changing table structure)..
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

After that, I saved it as HTML file and executed it with Internet Explorer. 
But, No response..  I found that after executing  'objConnection.Open(strConn);' IE waits for response forever..  Is there any library or program to be installed to execute all the code above? please give me some hints

Comment: You Don't use that script isn't safe and you add the credential inside a client page html so this will be showed by all peoples who come to your site. So the solution is server side connection with nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this (Works only in `IE`) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
connection.Open(connectionstring);
//your queries here
rs.close;
connection.close; 

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You really shouldn´t use client side script like javascript to access databases for several reasons like bad practice, security issues etc. You can use .Net, PHP, JAVA etc which are server side language and better way to use these to interact with the databases.

Comment: Still no response... OTL

Comment: You modified the connection string with your values, right?

Comment: yes Ip to server, DBname to Initail catalog, id to User Id and password to password

Comment: Which browser are you using for this? Please use IE.

Comment: I'm using IE installed on windows8

Comment: Is the sql server installed in your local PC? Please try with local and verify that your connection string is correct using SSMS.

Comment: ActiveXObject might be blocked in your IE, Btw same code works in my IE :)

Comment: finally it worked!! I missed the port number (1433) behind the IP address.. thanks!